# Are questions about advertisements on-topic?

Tags: support, scope

I'd like to ask when a symbolism was first used to promote something. Is this on-topic?

Answer (score 7):

Not directly. However, [history](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) is for:

> History of computers, digital electronics, hardware manufacturers, and software developers.

If the thing being promoted was one of these (and qualifies as retro), I think the question would be on-topic.